# Python Pandas Get A Sİngle Value From Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My input pandas dataframe look like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ ['AC', 'CompleteWeight', '0.2'],
['BB', 'CompleteWeight', '0.3'], ['RPL', 'CompleteWeight', '0.1'],
['IA', 'MultiPackageCompleteWeight', '0.2'],
['RPL', 'MultiPackageCompleteWeight', '0.5']],
columns=['Run Type', 'Name', 'Value'])
```

```
>>> df
  Run Type                        Name Value
0       AC              CompleteWeight   0.2
1       BB              CompleteWeight   0.3
2      RPL              CompleteWeight   0.1
3       IA  MultiPackageCompleteWeight   0.2
4      RPL  MultiPackageCompleteWeight   0.5
>>>
```

I want to get only 0.5 in "Value" column with using Column & Row names not the indexes.

Desired output is;

```
Desired =0.5
```

Could you please help me about this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to identify that `0.5` values what would be your rules or approach(explain only)?

Comment: `Desired = df[(df['Run Type'] == 'RPL') & (df['Name'] == 'MultiPackageCompleteWeight')]['Value'][0]`

Comment: Sorry about that, 0.5 is last row' s values. I want to get that filtering Run type and Name columns.

Comment: assuming 'Run Type' is your index column `df.loc['RPL','Value']`

Comment: you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`] (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to  get value using using Column & Row names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then select first value:

```
mask = (df['Run Type'] == 'RPL') & (df['Name'] == 'MultiPackageCompleteWeight')
desired = df.loc[mask, 'Value'].values[0]
#alternative
#Desired = df.loc[mask, 'Value'].iat[0]
print(desired)
0.5
```

If possible `RPL` or `MultiPackageCompleteWeight` not exist:

```
desired = next(iter(df.loc[mask, 'Value']), 'no match')
print(desired)
```